# Rails how iterate has_one though?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the scenario:

so, the product did not have any relation with feedback, but the order has
and i would like to show the feedbacks as belongs to products

```
model FEEDBACK

 has_one :order
 has_one :product, through: :order 

model ORDER

  belongs_to :product, touch: true
  belongs_to :feedback

model PRODUCT


  has_many :feedbacks
  has_many :orders
```

i'm would like to get the feedbacks of the product on a loop

for exemple

```
controller HOME


    @total_feedbacks = Feedback.joins(:product).where('products.id = ?', @product.id).where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').count


    @average_rating_from_buyers = Feedback.joins(:product).where('products.id = ?', @product.id).where('buyer_feedback_date is not null').rated(Feedback::FROM_BUYERS).average(:buyer_rating)






view HOME



  <table id="posts" class="product_table">
        <tbody class="page">
          <tr>
            <% @products.last(22).each do |product|%>

              <td>
                <%=link_to product_path(product.id), :class=>"product" do %>

                  <span class="productName">
                    <%=product.name %></span>
                  <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price, :unit=> "R$") %></span>


              <% if product.vitrine.feedbacks.present? %>
                    <div class="productFeeback">
                      <div><%= @average_rating_from_buyers %>"></div>
                      <%=@total_feedbacks %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>

                <% end %>
              </td>
            <% end %>
          </tr>



        </tbody>
      </table>
```

with this code i'm getting

> undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

someone have a hint to spare? thank's

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is like an online reference site where grammar and spelling are important. Please use a grammar checker and/or spelling checker before posting.

Answer (score 0):

On your Product model, try:

`has_many :feedbacks, through: :orders`

For the "Undefined method id" error, it would help if you could include a bit more of your stack trace.

Just based on the example code, I think it would have to be happening in the controller. @product.id is being referenced, but I don't see @product being set.

Comment: thank you Nick. @product being set you mean on controller home or in feedback method?

Comment: @product shows up in the controller code and in the view code, so I'd expect it to be set in the controller, so that it would be available in both.